# Change Broadcom Wireless adapter MAC addres to any address

Tags: windows-7, networking, mac-address

I need to change my MAC address of `Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter` to address of my choice - I need to mask myself as another device in the network. The conflict of the devices will not happen.
Under windows 7 it seems that either the OS or the card driver is ignoring/rejecting all addresses except those that begin with `02` occet.
Are there some cracked drivers or other ways to bypass to protection?

Comment: You do understand that if this other device is on the network you will cause a conflict right?

Comment: Yeah, I do. There are many inactive (or even not existing) devices in the whitelist. Please leave any comments how should I improve my question, after you vote down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These mac combinations will all work on windows 7.

```
X2-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX
X6-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX
XA-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX
XE-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX

X - is any hexadecimal number ( they don't have to be the same ).
```

Comment: Oh man thank you! Unfortunatelly, I can only use `0`, `4` and `C`. Is there some reason why theese numbers? I've noticed that they are in `{2+4(x-1)}` pattern.

Comment: I meant why they have chosen this four numbers, instead of ed.: `[1,2,3,4]`. I don't even state that the reason must exist.

Comment: @TomášZato [Macshift](http://devices.natetrue.com/macshift/) will change your mac to any address. (Tested on Win 7)

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this one did not change it even to the Win7 legal values. No effect on restarting device, but it states that the device has been found.

Comment: Either you're using it incorrectly or there is some other problem with your computer.

Comment: Well yeah, there is no third option in the end... I think that the device manufacturer matters too. And maybe I've also already made some mess in configuration with my prewious attempts.

Answer (score 0):

**Broadcom Wireless cannot change / spoof MAC address....SOLVED**

Looks like it is an issue with Broadcom WiFi drivers that do not support spoofing the MAC address to any random number. I can change the MAC of my LAN adapter (nVidia) to any MAC address but not the WiFi one on the very same system.
The suggested solution works for the WiFi (strangely)