# How do I change WiFi adapter MAC address for Win7/8/10? Network adapter 'Advanced' tab is missing 'Network Address' field

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, mac-address

How can I change the wireless adapter MAC address when there is no `Network Address` option under `Advanced` tab?

I have followed the steps `Device manager -> Network adapters -> properties -> Advanced` but there is no option 'Network address' or similar.

Operating System: Win 7 Pro

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you do this, there are bit rules you should follow follow so that you don't set it to a broadcast MAC address, and you do set set it to locally administered.

Comment: Because the wifi router gives internet only if the mac-address is on the list. So, for my second laptop I must either access the router and modify the list or just change the mac-address and make it the same with this of my first laptop. So, what are the rules that I must follow if the wireless card doesn't support this option?

Comment: Well, if you end up with two devices having the same MAC address on the same LAN, you will not be happy with the results. You should just add the second MAC address to the router's list.

Comment: P.S.:In my case it's not something illegal because I already have the password for the internet.

Comment: No, I don't want to use them at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit of a late answer but adding this here for future visitors and for my own reference.

It's possible to add the missing `Network Address` field manually by modifying the registry. Find the following registry key path:

> `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\00xx\NDI\params`

Where `00xx` is replaced with the numerical key associated with your network adapter of interest(search by checking the `DriverDesc` string value). Under `params` create a new subkey `NetworkAddress`. Add the following string values under `NetworkAddress`:

```
"optional"="1"
"type"="edit"
"uppercase"="1"
"limittext"="12"
"paramdesc"="Network Address"
```

Now check under the `Advance` tab again, `Network Address` should show up there now. Note that when changing the MAC make sure it starts with either `02`, `06`, `0A` or `0E` otherwise it might not work. Seems to be a Windows restriction or limitation. ([See this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/550140/54967))

Here's a full sample .reg file that adds the `Network Address` field to the NIC in question:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0009\NDI\params\NetworkAddress]
"optional"="1"
"type"="edit"
"uppercase"="1"
"limittext"="12"
"paramdesc"="Network Address"
```

In my case, my wifi adapter happens to be on `0009`. Change that to fit your particular machine.

Answer (score 0):

You 'cannot' change a MAC address, it is a 48-bit sequence hardcoded by manufacturer and supposed to be like the VIN on a car, specifically identifying that car or in our case, the network adapter.

That being said, here is a link to another question where several MAC spoofers are listed.  The ability to change this is dependent on your network drivers, and not all of them give you the option.  If you don't have the Advanced option in properties, your NIC will probably not allow spoofing.
[Change Broadcom Wireless adapter MAC addres to any address](https://superuser.com/questions/549480/change-broadcom-wireless-adapter-mac-addres-to-any-address?rq=1)

http://www.wikihow.com/Spoof-a-MAC-Address

http://www.howtogeek.com/192173/how-and-why-to-change-your-mac-address-on-windows-linux-and-mac/

Haven't tried downloading this and running a virus scan on it(which would probably throw warnings anyway as it changes registry keys) but it looks promising http://snaked-bytes.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-change-your-mac-address-in.html .   Since it does change a registry key it looks like here http://snaked-bytes.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-change-your-mac-address-in.html you may be able to find yours.

Comment: Replace "cannot" with "should not".  Some cards have been known to store MAC in NVRAM, and could be changed with specialized software that may only work with certain cards (possibly in a manufacturer-specific, non-standardized way).  How else would you respond to a situation of having two cards with the same MAC address?  (e.g., notice the serial numbers mismatch in [example duplicate address](http://i.imgur.com/RcbIA.jpg)...  I've heard from multiple sources that this does happen, perhaps especially with warranty exchanges of specialized "server" equipment.)

Comment: Put the apostrophe's there for a reason, then listed 3 ways to do it.  Then you restated what I said in the second half of your second sentence.

Comment: So,my card doesn't support this option. There is no way to change it, right? Even if I Install Linux and use a macchanger-program, right?

Comment: I've never encountered a situation where I could not change the MAC address in Linux.  It's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem in my Windows 10. I managed to get it done (I know you must have solved it) by taking the help of Registry Editor. Please have a look on the steps below,

1. Open Registry Editor. For that press (Win+r), then in the dialog box
   type **regedit** and press Enter.
2. Then find the following registry key

   ```
   **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}**
   ```
3. Then search for subkeys named 0000, 0001, 0002, 000x which contains the details of the network adapters installed in your device.You can get that name if you check DriverDesc parameter.
4. In case you don't get the parameter name NetworkAddress, you need to create on in the same subkeys(let's say 0001) which will be a string value. Right click on the subkeys->new->stringvalue. Then after that enter a 12-digit values(Avoid hyphen,colon).
5. Now, get disconnected from the network.
6. Now again connect to the network. And you are good to go.

   If you want then you can check the MAC address from the cmd prompt.
   type getmac
   and you will get to see the new mac address you have given.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Based on greatwolf's answer, I wrote a PowerShell script that worked for me. (My device is Windows 11, ASUS laptop, MediaTek Wi-Fi 6 MT7921 Wireless LAN Card.) This script will find Wi-Fi adapter key in the registry, then add the *Network Address* field to it.

```
$NetAdapterPath = 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}'
$RegistryKey = (Get-ChildItem $NetAdapterPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {IF (($_.Property -contains "DriverDesc") -and (Test-Path Registry::"$($_.Name)\Default")) {($_ | Get-ItemPropertyValue -Name DriverDesc) -match "Wi-Fi"} ELSE {$False}})
$parentPath = "Registry::$($RegistryKey.Name)\NDI\params"
If ((Get-ChildItem -Path $parentPath -Name) -contains "NetworkAddress") {
    Write-Output "The Wi-Fi adapter already has the ""Network Address"" field!"
} Else {
    New-Item -Path $parentPath -Name "NetworkAddress"
    New-ItemProperty -Path "$($parentPath)\NetworkAddress" -Name "ParamDesc" -Type "String" -Value "Network Address"
    New-ItemProperty -Path "$($parentPath)\NetworkAddress" -Name "optional" -Type "String" -Value "1"
    New-ItemProperty -Path "$($parentPath)\NetworkAddress" -Name "type" -Type "String" -Value "edit"
    New-ItemProperty -Path "$($parentPath)\NetworkAddress" -Name "uppercase" -Type "String" -Value "1"
    New-ItemProperty -Path "$($parentPath)\NetworkAddress" -Name "limittext" -Type "String" -Value "12"
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).